# Looking for alternative (band-aid) for Synch .mdb Access Database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I've been asked for a quick turn around on this. The group I'm assisting has a .MDB database where offsite workers that don't have internet all the time. Thus, way back the team implemented an Access DB which allows for synchronization.

As their team grew bigger they started running into the following issues:

1. Remote synching – when an user tries to synch from a worksite, more often than not, the database will crash either due to loss of wireless signal, program timing out, or Inspector manually shutting down due to time (i.e., 30 or more minutes)
2. Multiple synchers – we are unable to synch multiple at one time (there are currently 34 users in 3 different territories). If someone is synching and another person tries to synch at the same time, the second user will end up with an error message. They will have to shut down their DB and try to synch at a later time.
3. Incomplete synchs – sometimes when an worker synch’s his/her DB, not all the line items will copy over to the Master file which can cause confusion during review.

Is there any work arounds or items I can look into to resolve these?
I have little resources and time so anything involving a new server might not work.

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though you are mainly adding new data from different field operatives, rather than everyone updating existing data, if this is the case then that's good and you could try the following:

Ensure all the tables have "Replication ID's" for the Primary Keys as this will ensure no two operatives create conflicting records.

The synchronisation process should then be amended to take a snapshot of said table/tables to a .txt file on the operatives machine and then this file transferred back to the source machine.

Then at the end of the day or more often if required, the master copy should be setup to import the new data from all the text files it has received, as there will be no conflicting Primary Keys you should be ok, just remember to insert only those where the Primary Key is not already in the table.

Hope all that makes sense : )

Comment: It seems to make sense.  So instead of "synchronization", have the offline users get a txt export and the internet users pick it up

Comment: @ds_12_will More all remote users (online or offline) export to a text file, this can then be transferred back to the main master copy in the office or wherever it lives and all the data can be imported in at the end of the day for example.  Do all the users need to view each others data or just add the new stuff which they are doing?

Comment: Just add what they're doing.

They could potentially update previous day records. 

I think the solution you are proposing would work best, I would just  need to create syntax to check if the record is new or used.

how would this look if multiple tables are updated?  Make the text.txt file have the table name?

Comment: @ds_12_will You could incorporate the table name to help with which tables are updated, I would also bring in the user's name and the current date/time to ensure all your text files have unique names. You shouldn't need to create a syntax to check the records as if you use the "Replication ID" method I mentioned, all the records will be unique anyway even from different users.

Comment: Are there specifics to setting up the Replication ID?  Never have heard of it before

Comment: @ds_12_will Essentially you have to use the built in "Autonumber" feature for all of your table primary keys, on the autonumber it gives you a type option where you can select "Replication ID" which ensures unique numbers are always given even across different computers. There are some brief details here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoNumber)